# How do you achieve fast pointer scans?

Tags: c#, windows, pointers, memory, reverse-engineering

I am trying to build a utility to automate the finding of pointers after a program update. The issue I am running into is that the actual searching of a specific 4/8 byte value appears quick, but is not quick enough to achieve scanning for pointer paths.

Here is what I currently have for searching memory regions from `VirtualQueryEx`

```
public List<MemoryScanResult> Search(MemoryRegion region, byte[] targetValue)
{
    var results = new List<MemoryScanResult>();
    var buffer = region.Cache;
    
    switch (targetValue.Length)
    {
        case 8:
            CheckBufferUnsignedLong(BitConverter.ToUInt64(targetValue));
            break;
        case 4:
            CheckBufferUnsignedInt(BitConverter.ToUInt32(targetValue));
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();

    }
    
    void CheckBufferUnsignedInt(uint value)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* pBuffer = buffer)
            {
                var itemSize = buffer!.Length / 4;
                var values = (uint*)pBuffer;
                for (var i = 0; i < itemSize; i++)
                {
                    if (value != values[i])
                        continue;

                    var foundResult = new MemoryScanResult
                                      {
                                          Address = region.BaseAddress + (i * itemSize),
                                          FoundAtBase = region.AllocationBase == _applicationMemory.Address
                                      };

                    results!.Add(foundResult);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void CheckBufferUnsignedLong(ulong value)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* pBuffer = buffer)
            {
                var itemSize = buffer!.Length / 8;
                var values = (ulong*)pBuffer;
                for (var i = 0; i < itemSize; i++)
                {
                    if (value != values[i])
                        continue;

                    var foundResult = new MemoryScanResult
                                      {
                                          Address = region.BaseAddress + (i * itemSize),
                                          FoundAtBase = region.AllocationBase == _applicationMemory.Address
                                      };

                    results!.Add(foundResult);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

The application has 1.9GBs of readable/writeable memory broken out into 3,500 non-empty regions. Running the above function in a Parallel.ForEach with 4 workers reads all 1.9GBs in ~500ms and returns the correct number of results. That all seems fine until I start looking at pointer scanning and realize that's 4+ minutes potentially to find the very first struct pointer if I start my search 0x1000 before my target value's address.

The only piece of software I know of that has this functionality/speed and source code available is Cheat Engine. I've tried to look at the source code, but I can't figure out if it's doing something special or if I am just hitting the upper limit of what is achievable in .NET.

Are there any tricks I am missing? It seems unreal to me that Cheat Engine is able to scan and find 18.3 million paths before I even found the very 1st pointer for my value.

EDIT: One other thing is that Cheat Engine also doesn't have to cache the entire heap. Even during a pointer scan, it never comes close the memory usage I need to achieve my current times so I think it's reading the regions on demand. If I do that, my search becomes 900ms.

EDIT 2: Running in release (like I should have been) drops my times down to 160-200ms with cached buffers. That leaves my current benchmark at worst case 1.7 minutes with 4 workers to find 1 pointer. If just adding 17 results to a collection adds 50ms, I am starting to think I need to pivot out of .NET for the heavy lifting and make a .NET wrapper for that.

Comment: What happens to your speed if you omit the storing of results? Are you running a release build?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Good point! That actually drops me down to 165-200ms if the region's memory is cached. That does help a lot, but still leaves me at most 1.7 minutes to get my 1st pointer and CE is already done at that point. lol 

But thanks a lot for pointing that out. I feel dumb for forgetting that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Not storing the results puts me between 120ms and 145ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self answering because after a long time of fighting trying to build the scanner, I finally had an epihpany.

Every piece of information I found trying to build a working scanner was the most basic rudimentary example. Usually akin to something like this:
"Start at your target address X, walk up to Max N offset, and recurse checking pointers until you reach a static/base" And for the most part, that is correct, but is a giant trap once you start actually building the scanner. Using any bare bones example code will yield you extremely small results if flawly implemented or an extremely long process that you'll never let finish because you know it should be faster and/or you're running out of memory.

Here's the step by step pseudo example. But the main speed factor is this:

- Read all memory to make one giant pointer list `{.Address, .Value}`. `ReadProcessMemory` is too slow to use for anything else other than this.
- All collections should be sorted by Address.
- Use BinarySearch as much as possible. Maybe even make multiple lists for Pointers or Regions. One that is sorted by Address and another sorted by Value. We're talking potentially millions upon millions of items and a lot of loops. You need to pinpoint your items quickly and easily. This process so far has been just as fast as Cheat Engine for me, sometimes even quicker, but Cheat Engine at times may give me 3,000,000 pointers and I have 180,000, but so far have not needed the missing 2,820,000 paths. For comparison. I run with 8 threads, target app is consuming 2.5GBs of memory and the process completes in about 10-15 seconds. Cheat Engine with 24 threads takes 12 seconds. You probably only need a few. I arbitrarily chose 8 and Cheat Engine went off the physical cores in my CPU for its worker count.

---

### Step 1 - Memory Region and Module linking

- Grab a list of all Memory Regions associated with the process. Best to sort by the BaseAddress
- Grab a list of all Modules loaded with the process.
- Run through the regions and link the Module with region using their Base Address.
- Link your regions together based on their AllocationBase. You will now know what regions belong to which exe/dll.

---

### Step 2 - Pointer Caching

This is the first of two main speed areas. The goal is to never invoke `ReadProcessMemory` after this point. It's slow, there's potentially thousands of memory regions, and it doesn't consume that much memory to cache it.

- Make a simple `Pointer` struct that just holds the `Address` it and `Value` it points to.
- Loop through all memory regions and read the memory into a buffer. Loop through it with an alignment of `4` or `8`. `8` is fast, but may not give usable results in the end.
- In that loop, check the `Value` actually points to one of your memory regions. If it does, store your new Pointer in your cache.

At this point you should have a massive list of Pointers. From here on out, this is what the scan will be scanning against.

---

### Step 3 - Making Pointer Level Lists

This is the actual step and trick to having a viable pointer scanner.

- Make a `PointerList` class that holds your pointer's `Level` and a HashSet (or any other unique/sorted container) of `Pointer`.
- Make an array of `PointerList` based on the maximum pointer depth and the level accordingly. At this point I also linked my `PointerList`s to have `Next` and `Previous` that link to the other lists. i.e. Level 2 links to Previous Level 1 and links to Next Level 3
- Now that the lists are ready, we can fall back on some of the old rudimentary knowledge and start walking our pointers. BUT! with one major difference, we are not walking a full pointer each iteration. We are walking ALL potential pointers one level at at a time. This is why you want to use a unique/sorted container like HashSet (assuming you made the hash be your address' hash).

---

### Step 4 - Finally Looking For Pointers

All checks for addresses/values/pointers are based on your giant collection of pointers from Step 2.

- Level 0 -- Start at your target address, find all pointers that have it as its value, and add those to your level 0 list.
- Level 0 -- Subtract your target address by your `alignment` and check if that address has a pointer to it. If it does add to your level 0 Pointer list. Not your result list! Rinse and repeat until you reach say a max offset or node depth. For instance an offset 0x1000 or only take 3 or 5 pointers max. Up to you and requires testing.
  NOTE: It's quite possible to already have results in your level 0 list step. Check the address of what pointers you are adding and determine if it's a result pointer or just a pointer to work the next level.
- Level 1-? -- You have your initial seed of pointers in your `previous` list. Do the exact same thing as Level 0 and check your address for what you deem as a result or one to work the next level. For instance, only accept a pointer result if the pointer's address is in your main module's memory regions. Repeat this for all your levels. Remember the trick is to complete a level before working on the next level.
- As an example, your lists probably should look larger and larger each level. Level 0: 20 pointers. Level 1: 350 pointers. Level 2: 1,000 pointers.

---

### Step 5 - Building the Results

At this point if you went with a max depth of 5, you should have 5 `PoinerList`s that point to each other and there should be some results in some of the lists.

- Now loop through every list and their results. Keep it in the order you built them in and it should give you the shortest paths first.
- For every pointer result, you are basically going to be doing Step 4, but in reverse. Instead of subtracting offsets, adding offsets up to your max allowed offset i.e. 0x1000 or less if you come across your target address that you're whole scan has been searching for.
- Every result pointer you start with should eventually lead to 1 or more paths. The higher number of offsets/level, the more pointer paths you should find for a single result.
- This is the step you can finally start using recursion because you should never recurse more than your actual number of levels and at this point your level's pointers are highly filtered and targeted that you aren't looking at trash values.
- Run through with ReadProcessMemory and validate they work. Save/Use as needed.

Below is the scanner itself. Not the cleanest, needs some tweaks, but this is only as an example. The missing classes should easily be able to be inferred based on the above instructions and the context in which they are used.

```
public class PointerScanner
{
    readonly PointerScanController _controller;

    public PointerScanController Controller => _controller;

    public PointerScanner(ApplicationMemory applicationMemory, PointerScanSettings settings)
    {
        _controller = new PointerScanController(settings, applicationMemory);
    }

    public async Task ScanAsync(nint targetAddress)
    {
        var pointerLists = new List<PointerList>();
        for (var i = 0; i < _controller.Settings.MaxDepth + 1; i++)
        {
            var newList = new PointerList { Level = i };
            pointerLists.Add(newList);
            if (i > 0)
            {
                newList.Previous = pointerLists[i - 1];
                pointerLists[i - 1].Next = newList;
            }
        }

        var settings = _controller.Settings;


        for (var i = 0; i < pointerLists.Count; i++)
        {
            var currentList = pointerLists[i];
            var previousList = i > 0 ? pointerLists[i - 1] : null;
            if (previousList == null)
            {
                // 1) Start walking up the struct
                for (var address = targetAddress; address >= targetAddress - settings.MaxOffset; address -= settings.Alignment)
                {
                    // 2) Find all pointers that point to this address
                    var parents = _controller.CachedValues.BinarySearchFindAll(new Pointer { Value = address }, new PointerValueComparer());
                    if (parents == null)
                        continue;

                    // 3) Add all pointers to to the list;
                    foreach (var parent in parents)
                    {
                        var block = _controller.GetBlockIndexFromAddress(parent);
                        if (block >= 0 && _controller.MemoryRegions[block].Module != null)
                        {
                            currentList.Results.Add(parent, (int)(targetAddress - address));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentList.Pointers.Add(parent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // 1) Run through all potential pointers in the previous level.
                await Parallel
                    .ForEachAsync(previousList.Pointers,
                                  new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 },
                                  (pointer, token) =>
                                  {
                                      var nodeDepth = 0;
                                      // 2) Start walking up the struct
                                      for (var address = pointer.Address;
                                           address >= pointer.Address - settings.MaxOffset;
                                           address -= settings.Alignment)
                                      {
                                          // 3) Find all pointers that point to this address
                                          var parents = _controller.CachedValues.BinarySearchFindAll(new Pointer { Value = address },
                                                                                                     new PointerValueComparer());
                                          if (parents == null)
                                              continue;

                                          nodeDepth++;

                                          // 4) Add all pointers to to the list;
                                          foreach (var parent in parents)
                                          {
                                              var block = _controller.GetBlockIndexFromAddress(parent, true);
                                              var skipAddToPointer = false;
                                              if (block >= 0 && block < _controller.MemoryRegions.Count)
                                              {
                                                  var module = _controller.MemoryRegions[block].Module;
                                                  if (module != null && module.BaseAddress < parent.Address)
                                                  {
                                                      //This lives inside a module, however, there could be better modules pointing to it.
                                                      //TODO: Accept a list of modules that should only count towards the result
                                                      lock (currentList.Results)
                                                      {
                                                          if (!currentList.Results.ContainsKey(parent))
                                                          {
                                                              skipAddToPointer = true;
                                                              currentList.Results.Add(parent, (int)(pointer.Address - address));
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }

                                              if (skipAddToPointer || currentList.Next == null)
                                                  continue;

                                              lock (currentList.Pointers)
                                              {
                                                  if (!currentList.PointerAlreadyExists(parent))
                                                  {
                                                      currentList.Pointers.Add(parent);
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }

                                          if (nodeDepth > settings.MaxOffsetNodes)
                                              break;
                                      }

                                      return default;
                                  });
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Pointers Level {i} -- {pointerLists[i].Pointers.Count:#,###} pointers.");
        }

        foreach (var list in pointerLists)
            list.FinalizeToList();

        foreach (var l in pointerLists)
        {
            foreach (var result in l.Results)
            {
                var regionIx = _controller.GetBlockIndexFromAddress(result.Key.Address, false);
                var module = _controller.MemoryRegions[regionIx].Module;
                FindResultPointer(targetAddress, 0, result.Key, result.Key, l.Previous, new List<int> { (int)(result.Key.Address - module!.BaseAddress) });
            }
        }

        var r = _controller.Results;
        var maxOffset = r.Max(x => x.Offsets.Length);

        var sorted = r.OrderBy(x => true);
        for (var i = maxOffset-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var offsetIndex = i;
            
            //This is really hacky, but I want the main 1st set of offsets to be sorted and make sure 
            //the main big offset is grouped together as much as possible.
            if (offsetIndex == 1)
            {
                offsetIndex = 0;
            }
            else if (offsetIndex == 0)
            {
                offsetIndex = 1;
            }
            sorted = sorted.ThenBy(x => x.Offsets.Length > offsetIndex ? x.Offsets[offsetIndex] : -1);
        }

        _controller.Results = sorted.ToList();
    }

    bool FindResultPointer(nint targetAddress, int currentLevel, Pointer mainPointer, Pointer pointer, PointerList? nextLevel, List<int> currentOffsets)
    {
        if (nextLevel == null)
        {
            //The first pointer list is special because any results in it are direct and there's no previous list to build from.
            //Need to manually work it and add its results.
            if (currentLevel == 0 && (targetAddress - pointer.Value) <= _controller.Settings.MaxOffset)
            {
                currentOffsets.Add((int)(targetAddress - pointer.Value));
                var regionIx = _controller.GetBlockIndexFromAddress(mainPointer.Address, false);
                _controller.Results.Add(new PointerScanResult
                                        {
                                            Origin = mainPointer,
                                            Module = _controller.MemoryRegions[regionIx].Module!,
                                            Offsets = currentOffsets.Select(x => x).ToArray()
                                        });
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        //1) Find the child pointer
        var baseChildIndex = nextLevel.PointersList.BinarySearch(new Pointer { Address = pointer.Value });
        if (baseChildIndex < 0)
            baseChildIndex = (~baseChildIndex);

        bool hadResult = false;

        //2) Loop through all potential children/offsets
        var depth = 0;
        for (var i = baseChildIndex; i < nextLevel.PointersList.Count; i++)
        {
            var child = nextLevel.PointersList[i];
            if (child.Address > pointer.Value + _controller.Settings.MaxOffset)
                break;

            currentOffsets.Add((int)(child.Address - pointer.Value));

            if (!FindResultPointer(targetAddress, currentLevel + 1, mainPointer, child, nextLevel.Previous, currentOffsets))
            {
                if (targetAddress - child.Value <= _controller.Settings.MaxOffset)
                {
                    hadResult = true;

                    currentOffsets.Add((int)(targetAddress - child.Value));
                    var regionIx = _controller.GetBlockIndexFromAddress(mainPointer.Address, true);

                    _controller.Results.Add(new PointerScanResult
                                            {
                                                Origin = mainPointer,
                                                Module = _controller.MemoryRegions[regionIx].Module!,
                                                Offsets = currentOffsets.Select(x => x).ToArray()
                                            });
                    currentOffsets.RemoveAt(currentOffsets.Count - 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hadResult = true;
            }

            currentOffsets.RemoveAt(currentOffsets.Count - 1);
        }

        return hadResult;
    }
}
```